# How to disable MaterialDesignInXaml Button animation?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I'm trying to create a button in WPF with MaterialDesignInXaml installed, without the animation when clicking it:

[image: This animation here]

I've already looked through each property of the button and took a look at the buttons source code, but haven't found a solution.
The problem is, that the animation exceeds the rounded window.
I'm still quite on the beginner level of designing with xaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `RippleAssist.Feedback` attached property to `Transparent`:

```
<Button materialDesign:RippleAssist.Feedback="Transparent" Content="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable ripple effect, set `RippleAssist.IsDisabled` to `True`

```xml
<Button materialDesign:RippleAssist.IsDisabled="True"></Button>
```